# How can I solve installation error package?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, class-library

I create a Class Library on visual studio, I want to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore but I have this error :

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I already check my target framework and nuget version.
I just wanted to create a DbContext in my project in order to communicate with my database.

```
public class ContextLM: DbContext
{
    public ContextLM() :base(nameOrConnectionString: "ContextLM") { }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Install EntityFramework for .net framework, EF Core is not compatiable with .net framework

Comment: @satsvelke I already install EntityFramework but I can't communicate with my database do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You are inside a .Net Framework project, not a .Net Core project.
You should download Entity Framework 6 from nuget instead of EF Core to solve the problem.

Or if you want change project type to a .Net Core project if you have to use EF Core

Comment: I alreadty have EntityFramework in my prohect so if I can't use te method onModelCreating how can I connect to my database and communicate with it with entity framework ?

Comment: Maybe the project you are working on uses a Db - first approach ?

Comment: My database is already created in postgresql I just want to communicate with it.